# RCT-FOLLY - Thread-local storage is not supported for the current target

Tags: xcode, react-native, podfile

When I try to build my react-native project in Xcode I get this error from RCT-Folly:

{path}/App/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14Table.cpp:41:10: Thread-local storage is not supported for the current target

{path}/App/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14Table.cpp:56:10: Thread-local storage is not supported for the current target

I'm not really sure what is going on so im not sure what information I need to provide but here is my Podfile:

```
    require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Aware' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport'
 # pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec'
 # pod 'React-callinvoker"', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker.podspec'
   

  target 'AwareTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  #use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

I have tried:

- reinstall: Xcode, node_modules, pod and project
- deleting: build folder, DerivedData, package-lock.json, Podfile.lock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, and here's what I did to fix it

https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg/issues/148#issuecomment-633371018

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following code snippet:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'


platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'intimo_app' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'intimo_appTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  # add this condition
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer) # <- add this line
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer) # <- add this line
  end
end
```

Note: I am using RN 0.66.3.

Answer (score 0):

A different workaround solved this problem for me. Same error message `Thread-local storage is not supported for the current target` coming from a `.cpp` file belonging to `RCT-Folly`. Xcode was trying to build for `i386` however (not sure why).

(macOS 13.0.1, Xcode 13.4.1, react-native 0.71.0)

1. Select the "Pods" project in your Xcode workspace
2. Select "RCT-Folly" from the list of targets
3. Go to "Build settings" tab
4. Under "Architectures" -> "Excluded Architectures", add `i386` to the values for "Any iOS Simulator SDK".

`i386` is only relevant for iOS 10 and lower if I'm not mistaken.